# Unable to Launch Chrome and Firefox using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I could not find any solution to this issue, that is why posting here. Sorry for the sappy question.

I am unable to launch any browser using selenium webdriver. Please find below the details:

**Chrome Version in my PC:** Version 55.0.2883.87 m

**Chrome Path in my PC:** C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

**Chrome Driver version:** 2.26

**Tried with both selenium-java-2.53.0 and selenium-java-3.0.1**

Please find below the code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class testngtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    ChromeDriver  cd = new ChromeDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Pessoal\\QTPSelenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            cd.get("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Chrome Launched");}}
```

I am getting this below error in console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Sajjad\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: chrome
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.start(ChromeBinary.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startClient(ChromeDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:60)
    at test.testngtest.main(testngtest.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Sajjad\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.start(ChromeBinary.java:41)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Only IE is opening. Firefox is also not opening.

Kindly help.

Comment: What does the error message say? Did you google it to see how to fix it?

Comment: Error message says that it is looking for chrome in a particular location. Its in "C:\Users\Sajjad\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe". But chrome is installed here "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe". I could not find Local Settings in my PC.   I have googled it and i could not find solution anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because selenium is looking for the Chrome executable at:

```
C:\Users\Sajjad\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

To specify the location of the executable, set the system property before creating the web driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\executable\\location.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Still i am getting the same issue. As you have said, I have given like this  ` System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://google.com"); `

Comment: Kindly help,,,,

Comment: @Moha Does the output say it is looking for the chrome driver in a different directory. If you running java from the command line it is also possible to specify the executable there with a flag `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: @MohammedSajjad There is a great getting started guide with both java and python. Both examples show how to specify the executable path. Take a look, I think you'll find it helpful [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I actually had old chrome driver and selenium jar. Now i have redownloaded chromedriver_win32,selenium-java-3.0.1 and added external jars. Now working fine..